# Prove that $\alpha$ is an automorphism of $Z_n$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ r \in U(n)$[We define $U(n)$ to be the set of all positive integers less than $n$ and relatively prime to n].  Prove that the mapping $ \alpha : Z_n \rightarrow Z_n $ defined by $ \alpha(s)=sr$ mod $n$ for all $s$ in $Z_n$ is an automorphism of $Z_n.$ 
 
 I tried proving one-one and onto and this is what I got 
1)One-One
$$\begin{align*}
\alpha(s)&=\beta(s)\\
\Rightarrow sr\, mod\,n &\equiv\,pr\,mod\,n\\
\Rightarrow s&\equiv\,p\,mod\,n\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(Since gcd(r,n)=1)}
\end{align*}$$
$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$Thus $\,\,\,s\,mod\,n=p\,mod\,n$ 

2)Onto
$$\text{Since}\,r\text{ is a generator of }Z_n,\text{we know that }y=r^k\text{ for some }k.\\\text{Thus for every }\,y\in Z_n, \text{take}\,s=r^{k-1}.\\\text{Then }sr\,mod\,n=r^k\,mod\,n=y\,mod\,n=y.\\\Rightarrow\alpha(s)=y$$  I'm quite confident about showing the function is one-one.  Is there any element that doesn't make sense in the proof on onto?

Comment: What is $U(n)$ here?

Comment: I added the defintion of U(n). @qaphla

Comment: You've shown each map is a bijection, do you also need to show map is homomorphism?

Comment: It's definitely not true that $r$ is a generator of $\Bbb Z_n$ or of $U(n)$: the problem did not specify this, and for most $n$, these groups aren't cyclic and so generators don't even exist! Can you instead use the fact that $r^{-1}\pmod n$ exists?

Comment: Yes yes...Since I knew how to show that operations preserve, I didn't bother to mention that @coffeemath thanks

Comment: @GregMartin Well, I'm quite sure that $r$ is a generator of $Z_n$ since there is theorem saying that : An integer $r$ in $Z_n$ is a generator of $Z_n$ if and only if gcd$(r,n)=1$. The $r$ mentioned is precisely that.

Comment: @GregMartin I'm sorry if I have confused you, $Z_n$ is the group with  set {$0,1,2,.\,.\,.\,n-1$} and operation addition modulo $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would recommend using the notation $[a]$ instead of $a$, since elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are equivalence classes, not integers. Also you miss the proofs that the mapping is well-defined and that it's homomorphism.

On the other hand your onto proof is wrong. Note that $Z_n$ is a group wrt to addition, not multiplication, so if $[r]$ is generator all elements are of the form $n[r]$, not $[r]^n$.

Anyway here's a proof I think is supposed to be easier. First of all prove that the given mapping is well-defined But this is true as $[a] = [b] \implies [ra] = [rb] \implies \alpha([a]) = \alpha([b])$

Now prove that it's homomorphism:

$$\alpha([a]+[b]) = \alpha([a+b]) = [r(a+b)] = [ra + rb] = [ra] + [rb] = \alpha([a]) + \alpha([b])$$

To prove that it's 1-1 it's enough to prove that $\ker \alpha$ has only one element, namely the identity element. But this is true, as $\alpha([a]) = [0] \implies [ra] = [r\cdot 0] \implies [a] = [0]$, as $(n,r) = 1$

Let $[a]$ be an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Then as $(n,r) = 1$, there exist an element $[r^{-1}]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, which is a multiplicative inverse of $[r]$. Now $[ar^{-1}] \in \mathbb{Z}_n$, as $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is closed under multiplication, so we have:

$$\alpha([ar^{-1}]) = [ar^{-1}r] = [a]$$

Hence $\alpha$ is onto and therefore it's an automorphism.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the function needs to be checked if it's well defined. Also I got your proof on showing that it's onto.

Comment: But I seem to disagree on r not being a generator of $Z_n$. There is theorem in the book(I'm reading Gallian) that says : An integer $r$ in $Z_n$ is a generator of $Z_n$ if and only if $gcd(r,n)=1$ @Stefan4024

Comment: @BijeshK.S $r$ is a generator and that's true, but note that we're working with additive group, not a multiplicative one. So $<[r]> = \{0[r], 1[r],2[r],3[r]...(n-1)[r]\}$, not $<[r]> = \{[r]^0,[r]^1,[r]^2,[r]^3...[r]^{n-1}\}$

Comment: Yes I know, it's additive. What $r^k$ means to say is that $r$ is operated $k$ times with respect to whatever that operation is....For example in $Z_3$    $1^2 $ means $1+1 mod\,3$.. Hence $1^2=2$

Comment: Exponential, at least in the book I read(Gallian's abstract algebra) means to say that $r^k$ means $r$ is operated $k$ times......... Anyway thanks @stefan4024

Comment: @BijeshK.S But then in you onto proof you can't use that $r\cdot r^{k-1} = r$. As this is actually $r\cdot (r+r+...+r)$. Because of this I tend to use the previosly mentioned notation for additive and multiplicative groups, respectively

Comment: oooooooooohhhh......Now i get it...... Thanks aloot. I failed to realise that  ...Thanks alot@Stefan4024

Comment: I'm sorry ..My bad